# Would an object decelerate at a constant rate when mass is added at a constant rate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Assuming an object's momentum is conserved but its mass is increasing at a constant rate, would the object decelerate at a constant rate? It seems to me that if $F = p'(t)=m'(t)v(t)+m(t)v'(t)=0$, then $m(t)a(t)=-m'(t)v(t)$, so $m'(t)a(t)+m(t)a'(t)=-m''(t)v(t)-m'(t)a(t)=-m'(t)a(t)$ and thus, $a'(t)=\frac{-2m'(t)a(t)}{m(t)}$ which is not a constant.
Edit: The object is in a horizontal motion with no external forces applied and mass is dropped onto the object from above.

Comment: It depends on how the extra mass is added - with the same velocity or not.

Comment: Please read about how to actually handle [variable mass systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-mass_system) first. $F=m'v+mv'$ is incorrect. Please specify how the mass is being added, otherwise the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the equation is correct only when you consider one-dimensional motion without external force and therefore, the total momentum must be conserved including the mass change.

Anyway, you don't have to go that further.

$m(t)\dot{v}(t) = -\dot{m}(t)v(t)$ and
$$\frac{\dot{v}}{v}=-\frac{\dot{m}}{m}$$
which results in
$v(t) = \frac{C}{m(t)}$ where $C$ is a constant determined by initial condition. For example, $v(t_0) = v_0$ and $m(t_0) = m_0$, then $C = v_0m_0$, where $t_0$ is the initial time. Once you know $m(t)$ by an additional model, then you can know $v(t)$.